# Selenium automation scripts with java eclipse into VSTS

Tags: java, eclipse, azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager, team-explorer-everywhere

Hi I wrote automation scripts in eclipse IDE using java. Now I am trying to run these scripts using VSTS, Test manager and generate the reports, check logs. More like an automation QA person trying to generate, run, modify (give access to other automation engineers as well to change the code) and save it to the repository for future versions. I have already integrated eclipse with TFS using TEE plugin but not able to figure out how to integrate Test manager with Eclipse to push my scripts and run. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Test manager to test your java application. VSTS build tasks make it easy to build Java applications. These same tasks also make it easy to test your Java applications. The example below uses Maven to build a Java application, runs JUnit tests, and uses Maven and to test the application.

[image]

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/continuous-test-java?view=vsts
- http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1403/continuous-testing-java-using-vsts-selenium

Comment: Thank you for the answer so out of reading many materials I understand that for automation testing also I am supposed to be using the same methods the developers use like clone the scripts commit and push the test scripts into TFS for a personalized master repository. This is my understanding please correct me if I am wrong. Also I would like to understand how to create reports, logs and share at one place so developers can look at the bugs.

Comment: Yes, you need to add your project to VSTS before creating builds. You could get started from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1?view=vsts. You'll see the reports and logs in VSTS after builds.

Comment: This information was really helpful, but I have some problem the above mentioned links and info is for CI/CD work for java. But if I have a situation where my DEV team working on C#.Net for development and I as Automation QA writing our scripts with selenium, java, eclipse, testng/Junit frameworks and also using Maven. All this combined as a framework for automation QA. So my question is will I be able to run the test scripts and generate results/reports on TFS/VSTs so my dev team can look into. This help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TFS could set permission to users and groups. To let your dev team view your builds, just grant them permission. Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions?view=vsts

Comment: Understood!! Means same process should be followed but set some permissions. When I build and run the test scripts. Thank you much!!

Comment: Another quick question is there any Maven documentation that can help me to build an application in java eclipse and push the code and build in VSTS and setup a release pipeline like explained in this http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1403/continuous-testing-java-using-vsts-selenium document.

Comment: https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/vstsextend/Selenium/ this might be also useful if somebody is looking around the question I posted. I am working on this write now. Not sure how it goes but just felt like this would be helpful.